Low Power Electro-Mechanical Battery Charging System
This is my first time posting in this forum.  It was recommended to me by a friend.  I have a background in mechanical engineering and am looking for some help regarding battery charging.
I have developed an electro-mechanical system that generates an AC signal that is 11.3V peak to peak with no load.
After AC to DC rectification, I am able to produce 5.29Vdc with no load into a small bank of capacitors.
I purchased a 3.7V 6000mAh Rechargeable Lithium Polymer Battery Pack on Amazon.
When I first received it, it had a charge of 3.84Vdc.
I tried to charge it just a hair more with my system and could see that the peaks of the sinusoidal AC signal were chopped when connected to the battery with the measured peak to peak voltage reduced from 11.3V to 9.45V.
After roughly three hours with no increase in the measure battery voltage, I stopped.
I then discharged the battery down to 3.71Vdc.  I also adjusted my system to generate an AC signal that is 10.2V peak to peak with no load.
After AC to DC rectification, I am producing 4.77Vdc with no load in the capacitor bank.
I then tried to charge the battery with my system.  Again, I could see that the peaks of the sinusoidal AC signal were chopped when connected to the battery with the measured peak to peak voltage now 8.85V.
I was able to raise the battery voltage to 3.73Vdc, but no more.
It is probably worth noting that I have seven hand wound coils connected in series that have a total measured resistance of 312 ohms.
It is probably also worth noting that the AC signal has a frequency of ~5.5 Hz.
I’ve considered discharging the battery further and then trying to charge it back up to 3.73V, but fear that I might be missing something and ought to seek some help/guidance first.
Please let me know how to improve the electro-mechanical charging system to raise the battery voltage closer to the value when received from Amazon (3.84Vdc).
Thanks in advance.

Note that this is not likely the correct SE for your question. Asking for one's "thoughts" is typically considered an opinion request and is also disallowed.

For anyone interested, this was asked on the Electrical Engineering stack in Low Power Electro-Mechanical Battery Charging System and currently has two answers.
